# On click - open a popup from different website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I have 2 websites . in one website i will give a link "request info" on clicking this link it should open a popup   which is implemented it another website.

is it possible?

code in **site1.com**

```
   <li class="request_info"><a href="http://site2.com/marketing/rfi.php" id="iframe_form_request_info" onclick="return false;" class="iframe"  id="requestPopupD">Request Info</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one other problem you have two `id` attributes in the `a` element `requestPopupD` and `iframe_form_request_info`

You can

```
$('#iframe_form_request_info').click(function(){
    window.open(this.href); // also pass any other properties you want
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To open a link as a pop up:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
function newPopup(url) {
popupWindow = window.open( // specifics u can change
url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://site1.com');">Open a popup window</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open a window with pure JS like this:

```
function openWindow() {
    var win = window.open('http://google.com','','width=200,height=100');

    //manipulate win if you want to (eg. win.write("text");)

    win.focus();
}
```

And to call it on your button click:

```
<li class="request_info"><a href="javascript:openWindow()" id="iframe_form_request_info" onclick="return false;" class="iframe"  id="requestPopupD">Request Info</a></li>
```